# Make Related questions take multiple tags into account better?

Tags: feature-request

A feature request, it seems like the "related" feature could use some TLC?

For example the list of related questions on this question seems entirely irrelevant and yet the question has a very relevant tag [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js) and the question itself seems to have enough useful words that suggests the related questions function should be able to deliver a better list.

[image]

I have almost no experience in search so I have no idea what to suggest to fix this. Maybe weight tags in by `1 / popularity` since maybe the more obscure a tag the more likely it's the strongest signal of relatedness?